# How to set forum to the default main page in vbulletin 5.2.0

Tags: vbulletin

I am using vbulletin version 5.2.0, i need to set forum.php to the default main page.

I saw the [How do you change vbulletin's home page to the forums instead of the default (CMS or Activity Stream)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050124/how-do-you-change-vbulletins-home-page-to-the-forums-instead-of-the-default-cm) ,but i did not find the solution ,i think this post is for only version 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to login in admincp and then goto site builder then open a default page ,click on save option first you have to save this url to another url after that open url which you want to default and save as home url